# Can't seem to get cin.getline to work help please?

Tags: c++, cin, getline

Trying to get cin to input to the array, I have the correct header for it but whenever I run the cin part it just skips it and does nothing, I want it to be able to cin a line of text with the spaces.

```
char a[2000];
cin.getline(a, 2000);
questionsArray[y] = a;
```

**edit:** this is within a switch statement although can't see how it would affect it?

Comment: A) You should use `std::string`, B) `questionsArray[y] = a;` I'm afraid this doesn't do what you think it does. And if this is in a loop with a stack array, it's unsafe.

Comment: Two cases when it may *seem* like it is skipped is when either the stream is in an error state, or the next character in the stream is a newline.

Comment: I think it allows you to use cin to input a line of text with spaces into an array, so please tell me how wrong I am there and anyway of doing that would be very appreciated

Comment: Maybe you should post a little more code?

Comment: This bit is mostly on it's own except it is in a rather large switch statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is the better choice, as it works on `std::string` directly:

```
#include <string>   // for std::string, std::getline()
#include <iostream> // for std::cin

// ...
std::string a;
std::getline( std::cin, a );
```

Comment: @bilbsy: Well then, what's the error? Because, standard functions are not in a habit of being broken.

Comment: It just becomes an overloaded function which I believe is from a being an array of chars

Comment: @bilbsy: Do I read that as you taking the `std::getline()` from my example (which quite explicitly declared `a` as `std::string`, and for good reasons), and calling it on *your* `char a[2000]`? Think about it for a second.

Comment: @bilbsy: I take it you're a C++ beginner, possibly coming from C. There are many reasons to take it slow and use only a subset of C++'s functions at first. But really, `<string>` and `<vector>` are about the first things you should familiarize yourself with. I consider any `char[]` in C++ to be highly suspect.

Comment: Wouldnt say beginer id say 3rd year uni student still finding shit ive never needed to try before

Comment: @bilbsy: I understand that feeling. But truly, `<string>` and `<vector>` are *the* two things from all that C++ has to offer that shouldn't need to be *forced* on you. If all you had before are arrays and manual memory management, those two are really a godsend.

Comment: I normally would use these but I am accessing certain variables within the array that I only know by place, but I also still can't get this to work, it no longer errors but it just skips and doesn't ask to cin, am I meant to somehow cin something before it?

Comment: I got it to ask for a cin now but it still doesn't accept blank spaces into the string it just dismisses them and doesn't take them in any ideas?

Comment: @bilbsy: Works fine here, so your problem is not with `std::getline()` but elsewhere in your program. FWIW, you can access characters in a string via `a[index]` just as well. I suggest you come up with a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) and post it as a separate question.

Comment: eventually fixed it turns out it was working after your fix all along I just wasn't editing the right value in the array xD simple mistakes :P